# Transform Data with repeating attribute in each row to ARFF

Tags: format, dataset, data-mining, arff, large-data

I have a dataset as text file and data format is as follow,

ID: 1

Name: a

ID: 2

Name: b

ID: 3

Name: c

I want to convert this data format to be in arff format as follows

ID Name

1  a

2  b

3  c

Which tools should I use? It is a large dataset of 1GB with many rows. I got this dataset from snap.stadford.edu to practice Large data handling.

Answer (score 0):

How about use the **programming language of your choice**?

The input format is text, the output format (arff) is also effectively text.

Why don't you write a program to convert the formats?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the desired result with simple command line tools. If you have the data in one file called `x.txt`, use:

```
grep ID: x.txt | sed 's/^[^ ]\+ //' > a.txt
grep Name: x.txt | sed 's/^[^ ]\+ //' > b.txt
```

to get the data in two different files named a.txt and b.txt.

The files will have:

```
$ cat a.txt
1
2
3
$ cat b.txt
a
b
c
```

Then join the files with the paste command:

```
$ paste a.txt b.txt
1   a
2   b
3   c
```

This solution if very efficient, if the files are quite large, as you said.